# how to send array of bitmap to api in android studio

Tags: android

I have converted my pdf into bitmap array and now sending it to api using volly
but when sending i am getting its bitmap object,so how should i send it.
I am using lollipop api level 21
I am trying this from 2 days still not getting any solution.
below is my code

1)for opning pdf

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Pdf"),PDF);
            }
        });
```

2)for getting file path
here i am getting file path as    /storage/emulated/0/Download/Android test.pdf

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PDF && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            // Let's read picked image data - its URI
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String filepath = getPath(uri);


            File file = new File(filepath);
            bitmapArrayList = pdfToBitmap(file);

            Log.d("filepath", filepath);
            Log.d("getFile", getFile+"");
            
        }
    }
```

after getting path converting it into Array using below function

```
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> pdfToBitmap(File pdfFile) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            Bitmap bitmap;
            final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(i);
                int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 72 * page.getWidth();
                int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 72 * page.getHeight();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                // close the page
                page.close();
            }
            // close the renderer
            renderer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("BITMAP::"+ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("BITMAP::"+bitmaps);
        return bitmaps;
    }
```

this is the request that i am sending using volly

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void uploadDocuments() {

        if(isValid()){

            documentTitle = et_doc_title.getText().toString();
            discription = et_disc.getText().toString();
           // String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytesArray,Base64.DEFAULT);;



            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            ConnectionDetector cd = ConnectionDetector.getInstance(getActivity());
            if (cd.isConnectionAvailable()) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url = IUrls.BaseUrl2 +IUrls.uploadDoc;

                Log.d("url", url);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.USER_ID, userId);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.DOCUMENTS_TITLE, documentTitle);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.DESCRIPTION, discription);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.TYPE, type);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.LATITUDE, strLattitude);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.EXTRA, extra);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.LONGITUDE, strLongitude);
                    jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.DOCUMENT_URL, here i am sending data i received from pdfToBitmap());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("UploaddocJson", jsonObject.toString());
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            if (response.getString(IUrlKeys.ResponseCode).equalsIgnoreCase(IUrlKeys.Success)) {
                                Log.d("UploaddocOnResponse", response.toString());
                                makeToast(response.getString(IUrlKeys.ResponseMessage));

                            }else {



                                makeToast(response.getString(IUrlKeys.ResponseMessage));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }) {

                    /**
                     * Passing some request headers
                     */
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            } else {
                makeToast(IErrorMessage.ERROR_CHECK_INTERNET);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }


    }
```

i should get like

```
9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAOwA7AAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCAXLBHoDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAHgABAAIDAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAYHBAUIAwIBCQr/xABmEAAABgIBAwIDBQ
```

how i can get above bitmap format and where i am getting wrong

Comment: `converted my pdf into bitmap array `. Why would one convert a pdf to bitmaps? And how is that possible? What kind of image is in those bitmaps?

Comment: `getFile = getFileToByte(filepath);` What is type of `getFile` and what is `getFileToByte` doing?

Comment: `to api in android studio` ? You are sending a pdf file to Android Studio?

Comment: `catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`. If you have such an exception you should display a toast to inform the user. And then return. Dont continue as you do now as it makes things worse.

Comment: `jsonObject.put(IUrlKeys.DOCUMENT_URL, getFile);` As you use `getFile` here its important to tell its type.

Comment: Please comment. Dont just edit your post.

Comment: actually i wnat to send  bitmap array  to webservice

Comment: here my bitmap arraylist contains pdf

Comment: when i debug i am getting number of pages in bitmap but not able to get it from that arraylist of bitmap

Comment: some things were missing so i have edited my question so please see it again